# How to set the Simulator to use the exact resolution of the phone skin?

Tags: codenameone

As far as I understand, the Simulator zooms the UI to whatever window size you want, which is great. However, is there a way to set/force the Simulator resolution to exactly the same (physical) resolution as the device skin? E.g. adjust the Simulator window to have the same number of pixels as an iPhoneX screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `Scrollable` option in the `Simulate` menu of the simulator. It will add a scrollbar to the skin of the simulator and it should be in the same exact resolution without scaling.

Comment: I don't have a Scrollable option in that menu (it starts with Send App Argument)? I build with my own copy of the CN1 sources that are about a month old, can that the the reason?

Comment: It was changed to Zoom in the simulator menu. I hadn't noticed that

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it would be interesting to change the menu text to sth self-explanatory like "Native resolution"?

Comment: I don't like Zoom either. I think the menus should be reworked